# showing multiple promethese metrics within one graph of grafana node-exporter

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

Currently to show multiple prometheus metrics within one graph (grafana, node-exporter), i am manually adding the metrics in query options.[image]

i need to add multiple metrics which are in the form 'chat_msg_session_*random_number*'.
So, is there is a way to write query for this case, instead of manually adding the metrics to graph.